# Hugo incremental builds . Is there an undocumented switch somewhere?

Tags: go, content-management-system, static-site, incremental-build, hugo

I am evaluating [Hugo](http://gohugo.io) for generating my static site that will potentially generate about **20 posts a day**. So in about a year, there will be **7000+ posts** written in markdown, that will need to be build and deployed to my production server.

I initially started with **Jekyll**, but the builds even for small number of pages is terribly slow, and I can't, for the life of me, understand how a seemingly basic requirement like incremental builds - building and generating only content that has changed -- is still not supported in Jekyll... #SMH.

#### So I would like to know if Hugo has incremental builds?

I didn't see anything in the documentation over at [gohugo.io](http://gohugo.io/overview/introduction/),or in the `hugo help` commandline help.

But Hugo seems to have everything else I am looking for, and the builds on a small batch of posts is blazing fast, so I would really like to give it a chance.

Plus the language that it's written in, <kbd>GO</kbd>, was co-authored by 1 of my all-time favorite hackers -- Ken Thompson.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hugo currently has no incremental builds. The upcoming Hugo 0.16 will be smarter about building in server watch mode (i.e. it will detect what you change and only read that, testing indicates a ~15% improvement in the common case), but the builds will still be everything.

It will eventually happen, but it is a hard problem to solve in a simple way... But Hugo is very, very fast at what it does.

Comment: Thanks @bep Just saw your activity on **Hugo** discussion board. I was wondering, has anyone tested the build with 100K posts (realistic). I saw the youtube video 1 dude posted, but that is lorem ipsum with just 5K posts. Wondering, and thanks for this answer.

Comment: Have a look at https://discuss.gohugo.io/t/page-generation-performance-expectations/1335

That is currently pushing it, so for 600K posts to be a viable option, some kind of incremental building / caching would have to come into play. But it's not like there are any of the other contenders in the static generator market that does this today, is it?